# Posting viewModel and upload files with asp.net mvc 3 and knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

We are submitting an asp.net mvc view form using the knockoutjs postJson util. All works fine but now we want to add a file upload option in the form.

As per [Uploading file in asp.net mvc](http://%3Clabel%20for=%22file%22%3EFilename%3a%3C/label%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type=%22file%22%20name=%22file%22%20id=%22file%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type=%22submit%22%20name=%22submit%22%20value=%22Submit%22%20/%3E), we added the elements and the  enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in the Form but we do not get any files in the Request.Files collection in the Controller

Is there any issue using ko.utils.postJson? Is there any better way to upload files along with my form data?

1. All my elements are using KO binds so cannot remove knockout
2. We used postJson so that it can simulate a form submission and the controller can redirect to another view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postJson` src is doing a `JSON.stringify` on each input it creates and inserting it as an input element in to an internal form element:

```
for (var key in data) {
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.name = key;
    input.value = ko.utils.stringifyJson(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data[key]));
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

As such, file data from a file input cannot be loaded via javascript to be posted via the `postJson` call as it currently exists so your best bet for that would be to just upload the files and post the JSON in two separate requests.  It may also be possible to inject the file input into this form the `postJson` method creates (by overriding the method) but its kind of hacky and may not be forward compatible.

Comment: I am not using Html.TextBoxFor type syntax so not sure how it will bind with the controller model. I use KO data-bind on each input and select elements; I am using the jquery validate / submit handler to call the viewModel save method, which in turn uses postJson to submit. Earlier I was using $ajax. I am new to JavaScript so surely missing some fundamentals here

Comment: The model binder is used for when the data comes back from the client to the server (and is deserialized in to your action parameters) thats what I mean.  It can interpret both JSON or normal form post data, so you can use either.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this? I have a KO viewModel which matches the server model. How do I submit explicitly the viewModel + the file inputs to the server

Comment: I think for this your best bet is to do the file uploading separately from the model posting.  If you really must combine the two, one way would be to just have a hidden input you add data to and customize your model binder to deserialize that hidden input as well, or to use some of the javascript file uploading libraries out there.

Comment: I will just upload the files separately. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.